# Proof of Monotone Convergence Theorem in Cinlar's "Probability and Stochastics"

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Cinlar's book "Probability and Stochastics", the Monotone Convergence Theorem is stated as follows:

> Let $(f_n)$ be an increasing sequence in $\mathcal{E}_+$. Then, $\mu(\lim f_n) = \lim \mu f_n$.

($\mathcal{E}_+$ is the set of positive measures for some measurable space $(E, \mathcal{E})$.)

The proof then proceeds as follows:

> [...]
>
> Fix $b$ in $R_+$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{E}$. Suppose that $f(x) > b$ for every x in the set $B$.
>
> [...]
>
> $f_n 1_B \geq f_n 1_{B_n} \geq b 1_{B_n}$

I see that $f_n 1_B \geq f_n 1_{B_n}$ holds. My question is: **Why does $f_n 1_{B_n} \geq b 1_{B_n}$ hold?** After all, just because $(f_n)$ increases to some $f$ that's $\geq$ than $b$ for domain $B$, an individual $f_n$ may still be $< b$ for some $x \in B$?

I hope that I extracted all relevant context from the text for this question. The full proof can be found in Cinlar's book "Probability and Stochastics", chapter 1, section 4.

Comment: how do you define $\mu$?

Comment: $\mu$ is a measure on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ $\mu f$ is the author's notation for $\int_E f \,d\mu$.

You made me aware of a typo in the key part of my question. I fixed it, so now the definition of $\mu$ shouldn't be as relevant.

Comment: I get your point and I don't know whether this is correct or not. On Schilling's "Measures , integrals and martingales " the author says that there's an $a$ between 0 and 1 such that $f_n(x)\geq a f(x)$ for all $n\geq N(X,a)$ solving your problem but the continuation of the theorem is not the same of course. (What he does is to define the integrals and then let $a\to 1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope that I extracted all relevant context from the text for this question.

I didn't :). The crucial detail I missed on the first read is the definition

$$B_n = B \cap \{f_n>b\}$$ where $\{f_n>b\}$ is defined as $\{x : f_n(x) > b\}$. Now, clearly $f_n 1_{B_n} \geq b 1_{B_n}$ holds, because $1_{B_n}(x)$ is $1$ only if $f_n(x) > b$.